# pymongo : can't use resume token stored in Redis

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, pickle, changestream

I am trying to use pymongo to listen to a change stream while being resilient to failures / restarts. Thus, I am storing the resume token in Redis for later reuse.

Here is the code I tried

```
# Skipping pymongo and redis initialisation

if redis.exists('resumeToken'):
   resume_token = pickle.loads(redis.get('resumeToken'))
else:
   resume_token = None
stream = db.my_collection.watch(
            pipeline=[{'$match': {'fullDocument.type': 'something'}}],
            resume_after=resume_token,
            full_document='updateLookup',
            max_await_time_ms=500
        )
change = stream.next()
redis.set('resumeToken', pickle.dumps(change['_id']))
print(change)
```

The first time it runs, a change is printed and I get something stored in Redis.

But if I re-run, I got the following error:

`pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: The resume token UUID does not exist. Has the collection been dropped?`

I am using MongoDB 3.6.1 ad pymongo 3.7.1-1.1.

Anyone has an idea why my resume token is rejected ?

Comment: check resumeToken GET/SET value redis commands.

Answer (score 0):

First, that is not the correct pattern to use to resume a change stream. See https://docs.mongodb.com/ruby-driver/master/tutorials/ruby-driver-change-streams/#resuming-a-change-stream, adapt to Python as needed or check pymongo documentation for the equivalent.

Second, resume token is a document. If naively pickling and unpickling it doesn't work, convert it to a native Python data type first (e.g. serialize to an extended JSON document) then pickle/unpickle that serialization. You'll need to recreate an instance of the proper type when resuming.

Third, verify that after you read the stuff you write to redis you get back exactly the thing that you wrote. Redis is not a general-purpose persistence system.